# automatically enable whitespace mode in diff mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have googled on this but can't find any elisp script for this. Sometimes i do a whitespace-cleanup then diff-buffer-with-file to see what whitespace-cleanup has done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want whitespace-mode enabled for all diff-mode buffers:

```
(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook 
          '(lambda () 
            (whitespace-mode 1)))
```

Comment: `M-x whitespace-toggle-options` then `?` for a list of your enabled options.  Entering `t` and `s` will turn those on.